# Encrypting database of secret information: Entirely or in parts?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, aes

Imagine you have a database full of secret information, e.g. a list of usernames + passwords.

If you want to encrypt this database using an algorithm such as AES-128, how would you encrypt the data?

- Encrypt only the secret information fields, e.g. the passwords. Leave the usernames as they are. Output could be: "mike@example.org/AES_ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD;linda@example.org/AES_ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD"
- Encrypt the entire database, output would be: "AES_ENCRYPTED_DATA"

The problem I am thinking of: Probably, the data is saved in XML format. So a possible attacker could try random passwords using brute force until he finds an XML-element in the encrypted data. So it's easier to crack than the first approach. Right?

Or is it safe to just save my data temporarily in XML format and then encrypt the whole XML file using AES?

Comment: I wouldn't call an XML file a database. But you first should think of how you want to store and use this database and why (to whom) you want it to be protected in the first place.

Comment: Do you want encryption or hashing?  They're two very different things.  The answers so far are assuming that you *really* want hashing -- which makes sense if the purpose is to store users' passwords so you can verify their login attempts.  But if you're creating a system to store your own passwords so you can retrieve them (something like [PasswordSafe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/)), then hashing will do you no good; you'll need to use encryptiion.  What are you trying to do?  (Whatever is, you're probably better off using some existing software than rolling your own.)

Comment: Yes, I know the difference. And I really want encryption. You're right, I'm thinking of something like PasswordSafe. So I want to create a password storage system. But why should I better use some existing software? I think creating my own one is a good challenge and I can learn a lot about security in programming, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the OP, the question is more towards "known plaintext" and the size and redundancy of the message to be encrypted.

So:

YES, it *is* in most cases "easier" to break an encryption if parts of the plaintext are known, like XML-tags.

YES, it *may* become easier to break an encryption if more encrypted data is available.

BUT: All common off-the-shelf encryption algorithms, that are not yet considered "broken", are pretty immune against both types of attack.

In theory, it should in fact be safer if only short messages of pretty much random content (as passwords) were encrypted. If, however, encrypting *many* such messages independently, one would have to think about initialization vectors (similar to "salt") and the like to avoid producing patterns one actually intends to hide.

Conclusion:

Take a "good" algorithm with a good key/password/... and -if feasible- encrypt your "database" as one big plaintext message.

> Or is it safe to just [...] encrypt the whole [database] file using AES?

Yes, that's what I would recommend in principle. But be **very** careful how and where you store your data "temporarily"; a file in a "temp" dir, for instance, may not be as "temporary" as one is tempted to believe.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was asking for. You've understood my question correctly. So you agree to me that, at least in theory, it should be safer to just encrypt the passwords and leave the rest as it is. But in practice, the security is almost the same and one should really encrypt the whole data file as one big plaintext message. Right? So an attacker will not have an easy task just because he knows he'll find an XML-tag in the decrypted text?

Comment: Actually, what I meant to say is more like the opposite: You won't actually lose security when encrypting the whole database as one. However, it is *not* easy to do the passwords-only encryption right when handling more than some 10s of passwords (given the same secret key is used for all of them). Besides, the common cryptography tools will apply lossless compression to your data before encryption removing much of the redundancy in the data such as XML tags.

Comment: Oh, okay :) Thank you for clarification! So the result could be that one can just encrypt the entire database or XML file without any problems, right? One does not need to fear a loss of security in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same passphrase the difficulty would be the same whether this is a bunch of usernames/passwords or sets of XML files.

Only encrypt what you must encrypt. Though when it comes to passwords, encryption is not a good idea as passwords can be recovered (which will disclose them to the would be attacker).

It is better to store a hash and have a mechanism to generate new passwords if a user can't recall their password.

Comment: Sorry, there is a misunderstanding. I definitely WANT to be able to restore the passwords later. So I need more than the hash.

Answer (score -1):

Better to store the passwords as a hash with salt.

Comment: Please read the question again. I want to ENCRYPT the passwords so that I can restore them later ;)